# How does Gmail (google) hides its open from NMAP?

Tags: email, security, gmail, nmap

For a networking project, I am trying to "hide the open ports of the email server running on linux".

In regard to this, whenever I run a NMAP port scan on "Gmail" (mail.google.com) only ports visible are (**80 and 443**) both HTTP and HTTPS [Gmail NMAP result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA9fV.png)

However, Gmail is also accessible to people through email clients, which means that **port 25 (SMTP), 993(imaps), 465 (smtps)** etc. must also be open.

Now my question is that how can I do similar to my email server ? What concept / technique does Gmail uses to hide its open ports ?

ps: my email server shows port 25, 443, 465, 587 and 993 as open ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some incorrect assumptions about Google's mail infrastructure. The name `mail.google.com` points to Gmail's **webmail servers**: these are web servers with the Gmail web app that acts as a **mail client**. The **mail servers** are different machines. A Mail Transfer Agent determines where to send mail destined for `@gmail.com` addresses by querying for an **MX record**:

```
$ dig gmail.com MX
<snip>
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.                     IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.              3543    IN      MX      30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              3543    IN      MX      10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              3543    IN      MX      5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              3543    IN      MX      20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              3543    IN      MX      40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 72.14.179.5#53(72.14.179.5)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 08 13:47:39 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 161
```

So those `*.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.` addresses will have **port 25** open for **SMTP**.

In addition to the inbound mail servers, there are also **mail access servers** running IMAP or POP3. You can discover these by searching Gmail's help pages; they are, unsurprisingly, `imap.gmail.com` and `pop.gmail.com`.

Comment: @FuzedMass Glad I could help! If you found my answer helpful, marking it as accepted and upvoting it are the usual ways of expressing thanks.

Comment: I actually did that but since I am a newbie, i don't have enough points/reputation to upvote your answer. :-(